# Equivalent phrases for the term “war story”

Tags: phrase-requests

Looking for a compelling turn of phrase that means the same thing as a “war story”.

Specifically, I’m curious if there are euphemisms that convey a very similar feel, specifically that it’s both related to actual combat or war, and that it’s likely somewhat exaggerated.  Something like a “fish story” or “tall tale”, but specifically involves literal war or conflict.

Comment: And what’s wrong with “war story”?

Comment: Nothing's wrong with it, I'm looking for variety.

Comment: Epic combat saga?

Comment: In some circles, "war story" already has the connotation of something exaggerated; to make the difference, they say ["true", or "real" war story](https://www.ndsu.edu/pubweb/~cinichol/CreativeWriting/323/OBrienWarStory.pdf). Example: "They are out back, swapping war stories." and you know they are probably trying to impress each other. Those that have done, it usually takes them about 30 or 40 years before they can actually talk about it.

Comment: @Cascabel I agree, I'm looking for what are essentially synonymous phrases.   As for the Close voters, not very helpful. I don't know how to make the question better, and I could find nothing by searching to demonstrate my own research.

Comment: The problem is that if you are looking for a "compelling turn of phrase", the question is doomed as POB. Look for an existing phrase, if exists.

Comment: @Cascabel I am asking for an existing phrase.  I've not been able to find one, so I asked herr